# Different main entry point in package.json for node and browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript, react-starter-kit

In isomorphic react app I have **`myModule`** which should behave differently on node and browser environments. I would like configure this split point in `package.json` for `myModule`:

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "myModule",
  "main": "./myModule.server.js",
  "browser": "./myModule.client.js"
}
```

**`file structure`**

```
├── myModule
│   ├── myModule.client.js
│   ├── myModule.server.js
│   └── package.json
│ 
├── browser.js
└── server.js
```

So when I use `myModule` in **node** I should get only `myModule.server.js`:

`server.js`

```
import myModule from './myModule';
myModule(); // invoke myModule.server.js
```

On the **browser** side should **build bundle only with** `myModule.client.js`:

`browser.js`

```
import myModule from './myModule';
myModule(); // invoke myModule.client.js
```

[react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/core/fetch/package.json) uses this approach but I can't figure out where is this configuration defined.

---

### Motivation

1. `package.json` is good semantic point to do this kind of splitting.
2. Client side bundle only contain `myModule.client.js`.

---

### Known solution - not an answer for me

You can have this kind of file structure:

```
├── myModule
│    ├── myModule.client.js
│    ├── myModule.server.js
│    └── index.js           <-- difference
│ 
├── browser.js
└── server.js
```

And in `index.js`:

```
if (process.browser) { // this condition can be different but you get the point
    module.exports = require('./myModule.client');
} else {
    module.exports = require('./myModule.server');
}
```

The main problem with this is that client bundle **contains a lot of heavy kB backend code**.

---

### My webpack configuration

I include my `webpack.config.js`. Strangely this config always point to `myModule.client.js` for browser and node.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

const DEBUG = !process.argv.includes('--release');
const VERBOSE = !process.argv.includes('--verbose');
const AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS = [
    'Android 2.3',
    'Android >= 4',
    'Chrome >= 35',
    'Firefox >= 31',
    'Explorer >= 9',
    'iOS >= 7',
    'Opera >= 12',
    'Safari >= 7.1',
];

let nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(function(x) {
        return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1 ;
    })
    .forEach(function(mod) {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
    });

let loaders = [
    {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
    },
    {
        test: [/\.scss$/,/\.css$/],
        loaders: [
            'isomorphic-style-loader',
            `css-loader?${DEBUG ? 'sourceMap&' : 'minimize&'}modules&localIdentName=` +
            `${DEBUG ? '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]' : '[hash:base64:4]'}`,
            'postcss-loader?parser=postcss-scss'
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
            name: DEBUG ? '[name].[ext]' : '[hash].[ext]',
            limit: 10000,
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|wav|mp3)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        query: {
            name: DEBUG ? '[name].[ext]' : '[hash].[ext]',
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
    },
];

const common = {
    module: {
        loaders
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    ],
    postcss: function plugins(bundler) {
        var plugins = [
            require('postcss-import')({ addDependencyTo: bundler }),
            require('precss')(),
            require('autoprefixer')({ browsers: AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS }),
        ];

        return plugins;
    },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
    }
};


module.exports = [
    Object.assign({} , common, { // client
        entry: [
            'babel-polyfill',
            './src/client.js'
        ],
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/public/',
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        target: 'web',
        node: {
            fs: 'empty',
        },
        devtool: DEBUG ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : false,
        plugins: [
            ...common.plugins,
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env.BROWSER': true }),
        ],
    }),
    Object.assign({} , common, { // server
        entry: [
            'babel-polyfill',
            './src/server.js'
        ],
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '',
            filename: 'server.js'
        },
        target: 'node',
        plugins: [
            ...common.plugins,
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env.BROWSER': false }),
        ],
        node: {
            console: false,
            global: false,
            process: false,
            Buffer: false,
            __filename: false,
            __dirname: false,
        },
        externals: nodeModules,

    })
];
```

Comment: It seems that the `react-starter-kit` also has different webpack configurations for the client and server as well. Not sure if this is what is making the magic happen, but I guess you could take a look: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js#L202 and https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js#L261

Comment: @VasilDininski I have also two configs (only looks little different). In `module.exports` I merge two configs in array. The same is in `react-starter-kit` https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js#L309

Comment: Is the problem that ./server.js is not output, or it has the same contents as ./public/bundle.js?

As far as 'main' vs 'browser' in package.json - I don't believe webpack or the browser know or care about package.json for the most part, so you should just set it to the built server js.

Answer (score 14):

The behavior is standardized here: https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec

Although this specification is unofficial, many Javascript bundlers follow it, including Webpack, Browserify, and the React Native packager. The browser field not only allows you to change your module entry point, but to also replace or ignore individual files within your module. It's quite powerful.

Since Webpack bundles code for the web by default, you need to manually disable the browser field if you want to use Webpack for your server build. You can do that using the `target` config option to do this: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/

Answer (score 6):

It has been a long time since this question was asked. I just want to clarify the previous answer.

> If you look at tools/webpack.config.js in React Starter Kit you will
> see that it exports two Webpack configurations that slightly differ,
> e.g. module.exports = [clientConfig, sererConfig]. The server-side
> bundle config has this field target set to node (by default it's web).

It seems this webpack beheavior is not documented, but webpack automatically takes 'main' entry when target is 'node' and takes 'browser' entry when target is 'web'.

Comment: Jumping in even later here - I think this documentation is what we were looking for: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfields

So when `target: node` is set in your webpack config, webpack will by default first search for a `module` field - and if that doesn't exist, it will 'take' the `main` field

Similarly, the precedence order for `target: web` is browser, then module, then main

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `tools/webpack.config.js` in [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) you will see that it exports two Webpack configurations that slightly differ, e.g. `module.exports = [clientConfig, sererConfig]`. The server-side bundle config has this field `target` set to `node` (by default it's `web`).

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target

The approach that you described works great for modules that have exactly the same API but different implementations, like in the case with HTTP client utility that uses `XMLHttpRequest` in its browser-specific implementation and Node's `http` module in its server implementation:

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/tree/master/src/core/fetch

Answer (score 0):

To have a different entry point for client and server in a Node Module, you can use `process.browser` flag and handle the same

```
if (process.browser) {
  // load client entry point
} else {
  // load server entry point
}
```

Comment: This isn't actually a very good solution because Webpack will include a poly-fill for the whole `process` module.